# Need to preserve trailing zeros when converting from JObject to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I have a fairly simple request.  I am creating a json object in C#.  I have some properties that are doubles.  Originally, I created xml and formatted these values to have an appropriate number of trailing zeros after the decimal point.  Now I am creating json and xml.  I am generating the json using LINQ to JSON.  I then create and XDocument using JSONConvert.
But the problem is that if I put the double value into the JObject as an object and not a formatted string, I lose the trailing zeros than if I store it as a string.
Here is some sample code:

```
double value = 1.0;
string stringVal = "1.000";
JObject test = new JObject(new JProperty("sta", new JObject(
        new JProperty("@valDouble", value),
        new JProperty("@valString", stringVal)
        )));
var testXml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(test.ToString());
```

I realize I could just go through the JObjects I create and pull out the value and format it to a string manually with code.  But is there some way that I can have the converter treat values with a certain format.  So instead of getting

```
<sta valDouble="1" valString="1.000">
</sta>
```

I want to get,

```
<sta valDouble="1.000" valString="1.000">
</sta>
```

I hope I've explained the problem well.  I have looked through the Deserialize methods, but they simply have other options for choosing the root element name and whether to write an array attribute.  They don't help me in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually have found a solution for this, but it required a modified version of XmlNodeConverter.  To keep my impacts small, I actually made minimal changes to the actual code and then made a derived class.

```
//added this virtual method
protected virtual string GetAttributeValue(string attributeName, JsonReader reader)
{
    return reader.Value.ToString();
}

private void ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, string propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
    throw new JsonSerializationException("XmlNodeConverter cannot convert JSON with an empty property name to XML.");

  Dictionary<string, string> attributeNameValues = ReadAttributeElements(reader, manager);

  string elementPrefix = MiscellaneousUtils.GetPrefix(propertyName);

  if (propertyName.StartsWith("@"))
  {
    var attributeName = propertyName.Substring(1);
    //Made the change below to use the new method
    //var attributeValue = reader.Value.ToString();
    var attributeValue = GetAttributeValue(attributeName, reader);
    ...

// Modified to virtual to allow derived class to override.  Added attributeName parameter
protected virtual string ConvertTokenToXmlValue(string attributeName, JsonReader reader)
{
  if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
  {
    return reader.Value.ToString();
  }
  ....
```

I then created the following derived xml node converter.

```
public class DerivedXmlNodeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter
{
private Dictionary<string, string> _attributeFormatStrings;
public Dictionary<string, string> AttributeFormatStrings
{
    get
    {
        if (_attributeFormatStrings == null)
            _attributeFormatStrings = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        return _attributeFormatStrings;
    }
}
protected override string GetAttributeValue(string attributeName, JsonReader reader)
{
    Console.WriteLine("getting attribute value: " + attributeName);
    if (AttributeFormatStrings.ContainsKey(attributeName))
    {
        return string.Format(AttributeFormatStrings[attributeName], reader.Value);
    }
    else
        return base.GetAttributeValue(attributeName, reader);
}
protected override string ConvertTokenToXmlValue(string attributeName, JsonReader reader)
{
    if (AttributeFormatStrings.ContainsKey(attributeName))
    {
        return string.Format(AttributeFormatStrings[attributeName], reader.Value);
    }
    else
        return base.ConvertTokenToXmlValue(attributeName, reader);
} 
}
```

I then had to replicate the code that JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode does.

```
    DerivedXmlNodeConverter derived = new DerivedXmlNodeConverter();
    derived.WriteArrayAttribute = false;
    derived.DeserializeRootElementName = null;
    derived.AttributeFormatStrings["valDouble"] = "{0:0.000}";
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { derived } };
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(test.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
    JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
    JsonSerializer ser = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
    ser.CheckAdditionalContent = true;
    XDocument intoXml = (XDocument)(ser.Deserialize(reader, typeof(XDocument)));
```

I think these would be great changes to have in the Newtownsoft framework- to allow these hooks for customization.
I hope this code helps anyone else who needs it.

-David